# What is the difference between a ListView inside a layout and alone?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android programming and I'm just learning how to use the `ListView`. In reading simple examples, I came across two different layouts about using it:

1. Using the `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Using the `ListView` itself as the layout:

   ```
   <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/listview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```

Do these two have a difference? If so, where does each of them is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer; no there is no difference.

Long answer; the first layout can have more then one child, is a little bit more expensive in terms of drawing and performance.

On the other hand the second layout is more cheap and could led to better performance.

So bottom line is if you only need `ListView` use the second layout approach.